# How do I drop an index in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have below model for **user**

```
var MyModel =  new Schema({
  name: String,
  firstName: { type: String, default: '', trim: true }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

when I do to drop index from `createdAt` field

```
MyModel.dropIndex({ createdAt: 1 })
```

It throws an error

```
 TypeError: MyModel.dropIndex is not a function
```

**Mongoose version --> 5.2.14**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dropIndex`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#dropIndex) is a method on the native [`collection`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection) object of the model, so you need to access it from there:

```
var schema =  new Schema({
  name: String,
  firstName: { type: String, default: '', trim: true }
}, { timestamps: true })

const MyModel = mongoose.model('modelname',schema)
```

Now create index

```
MyModel.collection.dropIndex({ createdAt: 1 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Still getting the same `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropIndex' of undefined`

Comment: @DarkKnight Make sure `MyModel` is your model and not the schema as shown in the code in your question.

Comment: Got it thank you johnnyHk